# How does memset( ) work even for an array as well for a string

Tags: c, function, pointers, memset

As `memset` takes the address of an string or array and consider them as a buffer of character.

How does it know that the given value that has to be assigned should be assigned in sets of **1 byte** (`character`) or in sets of **4 bytes** (`integer`).

Comment: It doesn't, it is up to **you** to make it right in the `size` argument.

Comment: An array is a chunk of consecutive memory locations. A string is just the same, with the difference that the string is terminated by a special byte.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused by the fact that `memset` takes an `int` parameter for the fill value. `memset` cannot fill `int` arrays with arbitrary values - it operates strictly on bytes.

Comment: I have added the words "in sets of" to the question hoping that this will clarify things. I will revert if this is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memset always set that same byte value to every single byte. It has no way of differentiating between byte and integer arrays.
So if you memset an integer to 0x02, The integer will be set to 0x02020202.

Answer (score 2):

Except it doesn't. In the third parameter You must specify how many bytes to write. It uses the `unsigned char`(one byte) of the data in second parameter. So If You used `memset(ptr, 257, 4)` You would set 4 bytes to 0x01.

Comment: I don't see a reason to use 257 instead of 1. Why is that?

Comment: Theres no reason, the example is 257 because it overflows `unsigned char`. You could write 1 or 257 or 513 or 1025 or any number that is 2^n+1 for n>=8 because it gets truncated to the lowest byte anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to.. you have to provide exact number of bytes to be set as the last arguement to memset. If you provide lesser byte numbers, it will not set all the bytes